# What if I don't have entrypoint in dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

My child dockerfile inherits its parent dockerfile, can I not write `entrypoint` in child dockerfile, and assume the `entrypoint` in parent dockerfile will be used?

or must I repeat parent dockerfile's `entrypoint` in child dockerfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the new image will use the base image's `ENTRYPOINT` unless overridden in the Dockerfile or at runtime using `--entrypoint`